# How to get COUNT value for related table in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm working on glossary creating/managing tool in cakephp. Now i'm stuck on pagination of terms result.

For now i'm using this code to put number of translations for each term in terms index:

```
public $findMethods = array('translations' =>  true);

protected function _findTranslations($state, $query, $results = array()) {
    if ($state == 'after') {
        foreach($results as $index => $result):
            $countid = $result['Term']['id'];
            $translationcount = $this->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as translations_number FROM translations WHERE term_id = '.$countid);
            $translationcount = $translationcount[0][0]['translations_number'];
            $results[$index]['Term']['translation_count'] = $translationcount;
        endforeach;

        return $results;
    }

}
```

It's working, displaying number of translations for each term, but - i can't sort by that column. Probably it's because data is updated after query, and pagination doesn't know how to sort that.

But i don't know how to extend my query to get information about count of translations for each term.

This is what is in my Term model (besides code i pasted before)

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Translation' => array(
        'className'     => 'Translation',
        'foreignKey'    => 'term_id',
        'dependent'     => true
    )
);
```

And that what's in Translation model:

```
var $belongsTo = 'Term';
```

in database it looks like that in terms table i've regular id and term (besides other fields not important for this one) and in translations table i've regular id, related term_id and actual translation.

I hope it's all clear, i'm no programmer and all i do is by try/fail method - but on this one i'm stuck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you're looking for is [CakePHP's counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto) (scroll down a few lines).  It automatically keeps a count of how many related items that model has.

Comment: Well, i'll try it tommorow, if it's keeping track of how many Term.id can be found in Translation.term_id, should do the trick. Other way i was thinking was adding field to Terms table 'translations_count' and update it on every update of translations, but it can be hard to be sure if it's updated every time it's needen. More, i think that it could be done by some SQL function, but my MySQL knowledgle is less than desirable :)

Comment: Ok, looks like it's working - thanks for pointing in good direction :) i'm still amazed by cakephp and relational databases :D (and i've few quite big systems created - as yearly asessment tool for 500+ company :D)

Comment: @MarcinSerkies - CakePHP is awesome. :)  Glad to help!